# How to replace "&#8217;"?

Tags: android

I have a String `can&#8217;t` in StringBuffer(i.e. sb).
I want to change it to `cant't`
But when I try

```
sb.replace(0, sb.length(),( (sb.toString()).replaceAll("&#8217;","'")));
```

it gives me o/p at `cant&#8217;t`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sb = new StringBuffer(sb.toString().replaceAll("&#8217;", "'"));
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sb = sb.replace(0, sb.length(),( (sb.toString()).replaceAll("’","'")));`

Answer (score 0):

You can define string with <kbd>'</kbd> character inside the in Strings.xml file:

For example:

```
<string name="good_example">"This'll work"</string>
<string name="good_example_2">This\'ll also work</string>
```

For more info, check this Android SDK: String R